# Get current governor using RandomAccessFile

Tags: java, android, kernel, cpu, file-permissions

I have a problem in the development of a simple application to get some information about the installed kernel. More precisely, the problem is retrieving the current governor. This information is stored in this path `/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_governor` and to read it I've written this code:

```
public String currentGovernor() {
    try {
        random = new RandomAccessFile(GOVERNOR_CUR, "r");
        currentGovernor = random.readLine();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
    return currentGovernor;
}
```

This code works for getting other information like list of all governors, cpu frequency and some other.

In my opinion the problem is that the scaling_governor file has these permissions: `**rw-rw----**` while the other files (like cpu frequency) have these permissions: `**r--r--r--**`. The `currentGovernor()` method works on some device like Samsung Galaxy S2 but dosent work in Galaxy Nexus (perhaps because the file has different permissions depending on the device).

Do you have any solution that I could use to make it work on all devices?

Comment: What exception are you getting?

Comment: None. Being null, on Nexus, not show nothing. The problem in the Nexus are the file permissions.

Comment: Either there is an exception or your code executes correctly. Possibly it returns null, if the file is empty. Which is it?

Comment: The file is scaling_governor that contain the current governor.